# Can I remove the blue tunic?

Tags: zelda-link-between-worlds

Playing Link Between Worlds, I just found the blue tunic. Is there a way to revert to the green standard one? I checked on the Gear menu, but it doesn't seem like I can remove it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot downgrade your tunic. Once you have collected the blue tunic, you will wear it until you find the red tunic. There is no downside to using the better tunics.

Comment: Except that it's not green :(

Comment: Blue looks better on you, anyway. It brings out your eyes

Comment: Red is best. It conceals blood, whether it be your or the blood of your enemies.